# Android: Toolbar navigation icon Onclick shows accent color

Tags: java, android

I have a toolbar(Transparent) defined in layout file like this:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/business_details_tb"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/transparent"
    android:elevation="0dp"
    app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_w_background"
    app:title=""
    app:titleTextColor="@color/white" />
```

In Activity I am referencing the toolbar like this:

```
 @BindView(R.id.business_tb)
 Toolbar acceptTb;
```

I am creating onClickListener for the toolbar like this:

```
 acceptTb.setNavigationOnClickListener(v -> {
      onBackPressed();
  });
```

But while clicking on the toolbar icon it shows some unnecessary accent color. I have attached a picture to show it. It lasts for a few milliseconds just like a blink and does the back activity transition. I do not want to show the accent color while clicking. I did not find any solution neither I do not know if anybody ever faced this issue. What can be the solution here?

[image]

Comment: What is the android os version of the device? Have you checked on other higher api level android devices?

Comment: I checked with android 4.4 and it is not working there. trying with a higher android level is working fine